# How to update a rowData without the rows flickering when immutable mData is true?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

There is a requirement in my project where there are dropdowns in each columns og ag grid table.
And if one changes, other column should autopopulate.
I'm making use of cell Renderers to show this.
If I set immutableData as true, and rowIds are in place, on dropdown change, the other column values dont get reflected on UI even if rowData is updated. Badically, my cell renderers are not re-rendering even if rowData is updated.

If I use gridApi.setRowData, without using immutable = true, the row and table flickers and then updates.

How to update a row data without having the row refresh everytume some update happens?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to activate the `immutableData` you also need to provide a `getRowNodeId` function in your `gridOptions`

```
getRowNodeId: function (data) {
    return data.id;
  },
```

Comment: I'm already using rowIds like you mentioned. Whenever gridApi.setRowData(data) is used, is there a way to avoid the row flashing?

Comment: did try setting `animateRows=false` ? I dont know if this is what you want